# Python: using threads to call subprocess.Popen multiple times

Tags: python

I have a service that is running (Twisted jsonrpc server).  When I make a call to "run_procs" the service will look at a bunch of objects and inspect their timestamp property to see if they should run.  If they should, they get added to a thread_pool (list) and then every item in the thread_pool gets the start() method called.

I have used this setup for several other applications where I wanted to run a function within my class with theading.  However, when I am using a subprocess.Popen call in the function called by each thread, the calls run one-at-a-time instead of running concurrently like I would expect.

Here is some sample code:

```
class ProcService(jsonrpc.JSONRPC):
        self.thread_pool = []
        self.running_threads = []
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

        def clean_pool(self, thread_pool, join=False):
                for th in [x for x in thread_pool if not x.isAlive()]:
                        if join: th.join()
                        thread_pool.remove(th)
                        del th
                return thread_pool

        def run_threads(self, parallel=10):
                while len(self.running_threads)+len(self.thread_pool) > 0:
                        self.clean_pool(self.running_threads, join=True)
                        n = min(max(parallel - len(self.running_threads), 0), len(self.thread_pool))
                        if n > 0:
                                for th in self.thread_pool[0:n]: th.start()
                                self.running_threads.extend(self.thread_pool[0:n])
                                del self.thread_pool[0:n]
                        time.sleep(.01)
                for th in self.running_threads+self.thread_pool: th.join()

        def jsonrpc_run_procs(self):
                for i, item in enumerate(self.items):
                        if item.should_run():
                                self.thread_pool.append(threading.Thread(target=self.run_proc, args=tuple([item])))
                self.run_threads(5)

        def run_proc(self, proc):
                self.lock.acquire()
                print "\nSubprocess started"
                p = subprocess.Popen('%s/program_to_run.py %s' %(os.getcwd(), proc.data), shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
                stdout_value = proc.communicate('through stdin to stdout')[0]
                self.lock.release()
```

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

*** EDIT ***
OK. So now I want to read back the output from the stdout pipe. This works some of the time, but also fails with select.error: (4, 'Interrupted system call') I assume this is because sometimes the process has already terminated before I try to run the communicate method. the code in the run_proc method has been changed to:

def run_proc(self, proc): 
    self.lock.acquire() 
    p = subprocess.Popen( #etc 
    self.running_procs.append([p, proc.data.id]) 
    self.lock.release()

after I call self.run_threads(5) I call self.check_procs()

check_procs method iterates the list of running_procs to check for poll() is not None. How can I get output from pipe?  I have tried both of the following

```
calling check_procs once:

def check_procs(self):
    for proc_details in self.running_procs:
        proc = proc_details[0]
        while (proc.poll() == None):
            time.sleep(0.1)
        stdout_value = proc.communicate('through stdin to stdout')[0]
        self.running_procs.remove(proc_details)
        print proc_details[1], stdout_value
        del proc_details
```

---

```
calling check_procs in while loop like:

while len(self.running_procs) > 0:
    self.check_procs()

def check_procs(self):
    for proc_details in self.running_procs:
        if (proc.poll() is not None):
            stdout_value = proc.communicate('through stdin to stdout')[0]
            self.running_procs.remove(proc_details)
            print proc_details[1], stdout_value
            del proc_details
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key code is:

```
    self.lock.acquire()
    print "\nSubprocess started"
    p = subprocess.Popen( # etc
    stdout_value = proc.communicate('through stdin to stdout')[0]
    self.lock.release()
```

the explicit calls to acquire and release should guarantee serialization -- don't you observe serialization just as invariably if you do other things in this block instead of the subprocess use?

**Edit**: all silence here, so I'll add the suggestion to remove the locking and instead put each `stdout_value` on a `Queue.Queue()` instance -- Queue is intrinsicaly threadsafe (deals with its own locking) so you can `get` (or `get_nowait`, etc etc) results from it once they're ready and have been `put` there. In general, `Queue` is the best way to arrange thread communication (and often synchronization too) in Python, any time it can be feasibly arranged to do things that way.

Specifically: add `import Queue` at the start; give up making, acquiring and releasing `self.lock` (just delete those three lines); add `self.q = Queue.Queue()` to the `__init__`; right after the call `stdout_value = proc.communicate(...` add one statement `self.q.put(stdout_value)`; now e.g finish the `jsonrpc_run_procs` method with

```
while not self.q.empty():
  result = self.q.get()
  print 'One result is %r' % result
```

to confirm that all the results are there. (Normally the `empty` method of queues is not reliable, but in this case all threads putting to the queue are already finished, so you should be fine).

Comment: can you provide a short example of using Queue to handle the subprocesses?  I am not having any success thus far...

Answer (score 1):

Your specific problem is probably caused by the line `stdout_value = proc.communicate('through stdin to stdout')[0]`. Subprocess.communicate will ["Wait for process to terminate"](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), which, when used with a lock, will run one at a time.

What you can do is simply add the `p` variable to a list and run and use the Subprocess API to wait for the subprocesses to finish. Periodically poll each subprocess in your main thread.

On second look, it looks like you may have an issue on this line as well: `for th in self.running_threads+self.thread_pool: th.join()`. Thread.join() is another method that will wait for the thread to finish.

Comment: I changed the code to add p to self.running_procs.  This allows the threads to run simultaneously as I wanted.  What is the best method for checking the poll() response periodically for each of the p (procs) in self.running_procs?

Comment: I am trying to do this with 
while (len(self.running_procs) > 0):
    self.check_procs()

and then in check_procs I check the return from poll() to see if the process has terminated.  Is this a good method?

Comment: Yes. More or less, something like this: 
`while thread.poll() == None: time.sleep(x)
self.running_procs.remove(thread)`