# Why is my python script forking a copy of itself when it creates threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, fork

I have a simple python script which calls 6 threads and for some reason it creates those threads and forks a copy of itself. When I try to join all the threads it gets stuck forever. How do I fix this?

```
def backup_function():
    for todo_list in master_list:
        worker_thread = maint_tasker(todo_list)
        threadlist.append(worker_thread)        
        worker_thread.start()

for worker_done in threadlist:
    worker_done.join()

class maint_tasker (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,list1):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.list1 = list1
    def run (self):
        self.result = Popen("do stuff here", executable="/bin/bash", stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True).stdout.read()
    def output(self):
        return self.result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forking is being done by the`popen` call, not the thread creation, so seems to be perfectly acceptable.

Can't debug your `join` problem without more information. What does the thread return when asked `is_alive()`?

*Edit*: Mixing threads and forks may be bad. See [this article](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them) and blog link in my comment below.

Comment: So if I call popen in a subthread, the main thread will fork itself? It didn't always do this though. Even now I cannot get it to reproduce consistently especially with a debugger hooked in.

Comment: I did an strace on the main thread and its copy and it was stuck on futex(futex_wait_private...)

Comment: You seem to be confusing threads vs processes. When you fork using `popen`, the entire process forks. A little further reading tells me that [you shouldn't do this](http://rachelbythebay.com/w/2011/06/07/forked/). That blog link specifically mentions a problem with the `futex()` call.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255449/python-using-threads-to-call-subprocess-popen-multiple-times) may lead you down the right path... I'm late for *real* work!

Comment: +1: "Mixing threads and forks may be bad".  It is bad.  Use the `multiprocessing` package instead of threads.  http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html.  Only use threads when you can **prove** there are no workable alternatives.